# TYPO3 CMS Exception 1256475113 in Extension Manager

Tags: exception, typo3, typo3-8.x

I just made a new installation of Typo3 8.7.20, and when I enter the Extension Manager to download extensions I get the following Error Message:

> `"Core: Exception handler (WEB): Uncaught TYPO3 Exception: #1256475113: The argument "arguments" was registered with type "array", but is of type "integer" in view helper "TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\ViewHelpers\Widget\UriViewHelper". | InvalidArgumentException thrown in file /var/www/clients/client4/web9/web/neu/vendor/typo3fluid/fluid/src/Core/ViewHelper/AbstractViewHelper.php in line 356. Requested URL: /typo3/index.php?M=tools_ExtensionmanagerExtensionmanager&moduleToken=--AnonymizedToken--&tx_extensionmanager_tools_extensionmanagerextensionmanager%5Baction%5D=ter&tx_extensionmanager_tools_extensionmanagerextensionmanager%5Bcontroller%5D=List  "`

Another thing I recognized is that the "Function" to Create multiple pages is not working, the screen looks if some words are missing and when I click on create pages I get the message "no pages created".

What is wrong with my installation?

Comment: You can check your installation if something is missing/broken. Go to the Install Tool and do a System environment check.

Comment: Everything green, except:

blue:
Empty systemLocale setting

grey:
PHP open_basedir is set
No PHP opcode cache loaded

Can the open_basedir be a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if you have cUrl installed? Maybe the extension-manager is not able to load data from TER?

Comment: cUrl is installed on the server